# Select column and hide from other selects

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm dealing with a kind of message queue implemented in oracle 11.2 table. I know, it's wrong, still I have it.

Table consists of **id**, **message**, **date** and **status**. All new messages are inserted with status **NEW**. I'm developing java (jdbc) reader, that picks oldest new messages:

```
select * from messages
where status = NEW and rownum <= 1
order by date asc
```

Than reader processes message and sets it's status to DONE. It works good, while we have single reader. The problem with multiple readers is that, they all select same message.

I'm trying to solve this problem by updating status to WORKING. Is following pseudocode correct?

```
//autocommit is on
id = query(select … for update)
query(update messsages set status = WORKING where id = :id)
…do some processing in reader…
query(update messsages set status = DONE where id = :id)
```

Would it work for multiple concurrent readers? Would readers wait on locks most of the time? Or they will just get next not locked row?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple readers will wait unless you include the `skip locked` clause i your `select for update`. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS602):

> By default, the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement waits until the requested row lock is acquired. To change this behavior, use the `NOWAIT`, `WAIT`, or `SKIP LOCKED` clause of the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement.

[And](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55374):

> `SKIP LOCKED` is an alternative way to handle a contending transaction that is locking some rows of interest. Specify `SKIP LOCKED` to instruct the database to attempt to lock the rows specified by the `WHERE` clause and to skip any rows that are found to be already locked by another transaction.